# Passing arrays as parameters in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6, parameters

The following code kills VB6 (sp6) with an 'unhandled exception fault in VB.exe' on two machines in the office on the line marked.

```
''# Form1.frm
Option Explicit
Private ArrayHolder As Class2

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set ArrayHolder = New Class2

    Dim arr(3) As Long
    arr(0) = 1
    arr(1) = 2
    arr(2) = 3

    ArrayHolder.Add arr

End Sub

''# -----------------------------------------------------------    
''# Class1.cls
Option Explicit

Private m_myArray() As Long

Public Property Get myArray() As Long()
    myArray = m_myArray
End Property

Friend Property Let myArray(ByRef anArray() As Long)
    m_myArray = anArray
End Property

''# -----------------------------------------------------------    
''# Class2.cls
Option Explicit

Friend Function Add(newArray() As Long) As Class1
    Dim oClass As Class1
    Set oClass = New Class1

    oClass.myArray = newArray  <- This kills VB6 dead
    MsgBox "passed"

End Function
```

From what I can tell on various websites I am passing an array correctly but am I actually doing it correctly, and why is it causing VB6 to die so horribly?

Comment: Is there a way of hinting to the syntax highlighter what language it is getting?

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? The code within Class2.cls appears to be the same as in Form1.frm. Is this correct?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Where's ArrayHolder.Add? Why code in Class2.cls is same as in Form1.frm?

Comment: I was asking myself the same thing. And I wonder if it is really called "Class2", and if it is, why.

Comment: Sorry.  Cutting and pasting went wrong

Comment: Looks like it's still wrong. Class2.cls still appears to be the same as Form1.cls.

Comment: I'd love to be able to attach small zip files for postings...

Comment: Moved the edit line of the death. It was correct before but in the wrong file.  HAving a bad day.

Comment: I don't see an Add method in Class2.

Comment: Graham, I think you should accept Eduardo's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have an answer, and certainly is a curious question, but why don't just add a method and move on?

```
'Passed the test
Public Sub LetMyArray(anArray() As Long)
    m_myArray = anArray
End Sub


'oClass.MyArray = newArray ' <- This kills VB6 dead
oClass.LetMyArray newArray  ' <- This works
```

Comment: Curiously it does work.

Well I was working on making it a collection, but updating all the places it is used was proving to be a pain.

Comment: I think you just discovered a bug in the VB runtime. But we will never see SP7 :)

Comment: +1 for pragmatism! And, perhaps sadly, for being correct about SP7. The extended support for the runtime does not include service packs (I seem to remember)

Comment: @Erx_VB I admit it is [arguable](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vb6/topusers) that I should spend more time in the "real world"! :)

Comment: @markj Wow I am impressed I must say, nice stats! Apparently I am the second highest of those who "ask" lol and am lucky to have people like yourself to answer :)

Answer (score 9):

This is a bug in the IDE (compiled is ok) that MS never fixed. I'm using a workaround with a temp array like this:

```
Friend Function Add(newArray() As Long) As Class1
    Dim oClass As Class1
    Dim tempArray() As Long
    Set oClass = New Class1

    tempArray = newArray
    oClass.myArray = tempArray <- Should work now
    MsgBox "passed"

End Function
```

FYI, it gets worse with Byte arrays (Long arrays are safe) when you accidentally hover with the mouse over the param or the array property. Better keep your mouse away from the code :-))

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this happens, but if you anyway want a copy of an array, use a Variant in class2:

```
Private m_myArray As Variant

Public Property Get myArray() As Variant
    myArray = m_myArray
End Property

Friend Property Let myArray(anArray As Variant)
    m_myArray = anArray
End Property
```

Fixes it, but still, I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: When I tried a variant, it still crashed.  Maybe I did something wrong?!

Comment: Maybe you just did what I said and replaced contents of Class2 with this code. :) Of course, I meant to say Class1. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem appears to be this:

`dim arr(3) as long`
in memory this is no differnt to this:

```
dim A as long, B as long, C as long, D as long
```

it creates 4 variables (16 bytes) in the local stack memory.
there is no array header so this is why its freaking out when it goes to access one (cos it isnt there)

Allocate the array on the heap like this and it should be fine;

```
dim arr() as long
redim arr(3)
```

keep in mind that hard coded array sizes arnt really arrays in memory, they dont have headers specifying their allocated sizes since the compiler can figure them out at compile time and hard code them in.
Run time allocated arrays point to a data structure in memory that contains infomation abouts dimentions, is upper and lower bounds etc and a pointer to the actual array data in memory. fixed arrays dont have this they are just, a best, pointers to a block of memory, no array header.